I am getting an 'error occurred prerendering page' & 'location not found' error while trying to deploy my Next.js project on Vercel
Deployment errors:
Error occurred prerendering page "/admin/categories".
    ReferenceError: location is not defined
    at /vercel/path0/Frontend/.next/server/chunks/356.js:1:5918
    at /vercel/path0/Frontend/.next/server/chunks/356.js:1:6692
    at t.startTransition (/vercel/path0/Frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server
    /app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:108548)
    at Object.push (/vercel/path0/Frontend/.next/server/chunks/356.js:1:6680)
    at n (/vercel/path0/Frontend/.next/server/app/admin/system-users/page.js:1:2907)
    at nM (/vercel/path0/Frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/
    app- page.runtime.prod.js:12:47419)
    at nN (/vercel/path0/Frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/
    app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:64674)
    at nM (/vercel/path0/Frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/
    app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:59098)
    at nN (/vercel/path0/Frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server
    /app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:64674)
    at nI (/vercel/path0/Frontend/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server
    /app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:46806)

Here is my folder structure:
Folder structure
My categories page:
"use client";
import axios from "axios";
import "../providers/providers.scss";
import "./categories.scss";
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { Toaster, toast } from "sonner";
import Image from "next/image";
import Modal from "../../../components/modal/Modal";
import PrivateRoute from "../../../Routes/AdminRoute";

const page = () =\> {
const \[data, setData\] = useState({
   name: "",
  image: "",
 });

const \[popUpDelete, setPopUpDelete\] = useState(false);
const \[popUpDetails, setPopUpDetails\] = useState(false);
const \[popUpEdit, setPopUpEdit\] = useState(false);

const \[preview, setPreview\] = useState(null);

const \[singleData, setSingleData\] = useState({});
const \[categoryData, setCategoryData\] = useState(\[\]);
const \[id, setId\] = useState("");

const fileInputRef = useRef();

const toggleDelete = (id) =\> {
setPopUpDelete(!popUpDelete);
setId(id);
};
const toggleDetails = (id) =\> {
setPopUpDetails(!popUpDetails);
setId(id);
};
const toggleEdit = async (id) =\> {
setPopUpEdit(!popUpEdit);
setId(id);
await fetchSingleCategory(id);
};

const handleFileEditChange = (e) =\> {
const \[file\] = e.target.files;
setSingleData((prev) =\> ({ ...prev, image: file }));
const objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);
setPreview(objectUrl);
  };

const fetchSingleCategory = async () =\> {
try {
const res = await axios.get(
`${process.env.API_KEY}/api/v1/get/category/${id}`
);

setSingleData(res.data.category);
} catch (error) {
console.log(error);
}
};
const fetchCategory = async () =\> {
try {
const res = await axios.get(`${process.env.API_KEY}/api/v1/get/category`);
setCategoryData(res.data.getCategory);
} catch (error) {
console.log(error);
}
};
const handleSubmit = async (e) =\> {  
try {
e.preventDefault();
const formdata = new FormData();
Object.entries(data).forEach((\[key, value\]) =\> {
formdata.append(key, value);
});

const submit = await axios.post(
`${process.env.API_KEY}/api/v1/create/category`,
    formdata
);
if (submit.data.status === 1) {
toast.success("Provider details added successfully.");
  }
fetchCategory();
  setData({
    name: "",
    image: "",
  });
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
 };

const handleDelete = async (_id) => {
try {
  const res = await axios.delete(
    `${process.env.API_KEY}/api/v1/delete/category/${_id}`
  );

  if (res.data.status === 1) {
    toast.success(`Provider has been deleted.`);
  }
  fetchCategory();
  toggleDelete();
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}

};
const handleFileChange = (e) =\> {
const \[file\] = e.target.files;
setData({ ...data, image: file });
const objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);
setPreview(objectUrl);
};

const handleUpdate = async (e) => {
try {
  e.preventDefault();
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("id", singleData._id);

  if (singleData.name !== "") {
    formData.append("name", singleData.name);
  }
  if (singleData.image !== "") {
    formData.append("image", singleData.image);
  }

  if (singleData.status !== "") {
    formData.append("status", singleData.status);
  }

  const response = await axios.put(
    `${process.env.API_KEY}/api/v1/update/category/${singleData._id}`,
    formData,
    {
      headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
    }
  );

  if (response.data.status === 1) {
    toast.success("Provider details updated successfully.");
    fetchCategory();
    toggleEdit();
  } else {
    toast.error("Provider details update failed.");
  }
} catch (error) {
   console.log(error);
}

};

const handleEditChange = (e) =\> {
setSingleData((prev) =\> ({ ...prev, \[e.target.name\]: e.target.value }));
};

const handleChange = (e) =\> {
setData({ ...data, \[e.target.name\]: e.target.value });
};

useEffect(() =\> {
fetchCategory();
}, \[\]);
useEffect(() =\> {
fetchSingleCategory();
}, \[id\]);

return (
<>
<PrivateRoute>
<h3 className="categories_heading">Categories</h3>
<div className="categories_container">
<div className="category_form ">
<div className="category_heading">
<h3>Category</h3>
</div>
<hr />
<form action="Post"> 
<input
onChange={handleChange}
name="name"
value={data.name}
type="text"
placeholder="Name of the category"
/>
<input onChange={handleFileChange} name="image" type="file" />

....

);
};

export default page;

I tried using useEffect hook but it doesn't seem to work. I found other cases that worked using useEffect for blocking the server accessing front end browser specific APIs and objects. I can't seem to stop the browser from accessing these client side objects
